Pass-through of OBS Virtual Camera to QEMU
I'd like to use my OBS virtual camera in a virtual machine.
OBS will not run within a virtual machine unless I perform a GPU-passthrough, which I feel is unnecessary and undesirable in this situation.
Instead, I run OBS on the host and enable the virtual camera.
I am a novice when it comes to Linux and hardware, so I was hoping to see that it would appear on the list of USB-Redirectable devices provided by the QEMU GUI.  It did not.
I understand that QEMU is quite flexible when it comes to editing XML files - I used v4l2-ctl to detect my video devices.  The OBS virtual camera is set to /dev/video2.
What XML can I add to my QEMU virtual machine to accomplish a passthrough of this device?
If it can be done, are there any commands I will have to run on the host in respect of power-cycling the VM which is "grabbing" the output?  I'd like to continue using the Virtual Camera on my host when the guest is not in use.

"OBS will not run within a virtual machine unless I perform a GPU-passthrough", huh, never had that problem. What kind of error are you getting? Or do you mean that you want to pass through the camera device, not the GPU?

It's the virtual camera which I want to pass through, not the GPU.  Thanks.

What are you trying to accomplish ?

I'm seeking a means to access the video output from the host device /dev/video2 from within a guest machine.
Functionally, I want to be able to attend Jitsi and Zoom (and any other video chat apps) from within the guest environment, while showing the feed from the OBS virtual camera instead of my built-in webcam.
The reason I don't have to do this for my webcam is the QEMU interface provides a means of redirecting USB devices, but OBS virtual camera isn't on a USB port, and doesn't appear in the list.  I assumed editing the XML was the best approach.

Altering the /dev/video2 device so that it registers as a USB device (and therefore appears in the QEMU redirection list) would also be a great solution, but I don't know how to, myself.

there's no USB involved here and "Altering the /dev/video2 device" doesn't make too much sense. You don't have to pass USB from your VM to your host, you just need to pass video, which is much easier

I'm going to try to say this without being salty, but your contributions so far have been to make cosmetic edits to my question, ask me to repeat it, and now you tell me the solution is easy - but you don't elaborate.  Are you honestly trolling me or do you have an answer?
